# How to align view elements in Relativelayout dynamically through code in Android?

Tags: android

I want to display 3 check box one below each other in relative layout dynamically through code.But i am able to display only two check box one below each other. I am giving below my code....I am not able to find out where i am going wrong.

My Code -

```
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
    cb1.setId(1);
    cb1.setText("A");

    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(this);
    cb2.setId(2);
    cb2.setText("B");

    CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox(this);
    cb3.setId(3);
    cb3.setText("C");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

    layout.addView(cb1);     

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb1.getId());
    cb2.setLayoutParams(lp);        
    layout.addView(cb2);

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb2.getId());
    cb3.setLayoutParams(lp);
    layout.addView(cb3);
```

Thanks in advance.

Rohan Waugh

Answer (score 5):

```
layout.addView(cb1);     

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb1.getId());
cb2.setLayoutParams(lp);        
layout.addView(cb2);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb2.getId());
cb3.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.addView(cb3);
```

Thanks man this helped me a lot

I guess you are wrong at the point that you are using "lp" as the layout parameters for both cb2 and cb3(you can't add the same rule "RelativeLayout.BELOW" to same layoutparameters object "lp" again and again).
Use lp for cb2  and lp2 for cb3
and create like this

```
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
cb1.setId(1);
cb1.setText("A");

CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox(this);
cb2.setId(2);
cb2.setText("B");

CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox(this);
cb3.setId(3);
cb3.setText("C");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

layout.addView(cb1);     

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb1.getId());
cb2.setLayoutParams(lp);        
layout.addView(cb2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//important

lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,cb2.getId());//important
cb3.setLayoutParams(lp2);//important
layout.addView(cb3);
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Is there anyway to create a rule dynamically?
please have a look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048714/create-dyanamic-rule

Comment: Yes you can create a rule dynamically. but what do you actually want is still uncertain. Sorry for replying so late