# Use relative layout in java code

Tags: java, android, layout, dynamic, android-relativelayout

I m making and app which allows the user to change the interface by moving items like buttons, erasing them and adding new. So i need to know how i can change the layout properties (like toRightOf) of buttons in a relative layout through the java code, so that i can dynamically relocate them.

I have tried using layoutparams but i havent manage to find a solution. I have read other post that suggest using an absolute layout and changing the properties x and y. Is this the only way or can i use the relative layout ?

Please help.

Comment: post code with layout params, that is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use combinations of `addRule`/`getRule` from [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) class.

Here's a link to [some example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280844/how-to-align-view-elements-in-relativelayout-dynamically-through-code-in-android).